# parse text using grep regex pull out text from multiple lines of text in a file

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a chunck of text in a file:

```
<tr bgcolor="#F9F9F9">
     <td align="left">8/7/2012 11:23:42 AM</td>
     <td align="left"><em>Here is the text I want to parse out</em></td>
     <td class="ra">9.00</td>
     <td class="ra">297.00</td>
     <td class="ra">0.00</td>
     <td class="ra">0.00</td>
     <td class="ra">$0.00</td>
     <td class="ra">$0.50</td>
     <td class="ra"></td>
 </tr>
```

using grep I would like to end up with the result being

**Here is the text I want to parse out**

Working on the code now I have

```
cat file.txt | grep -m 1 -oP '<em>[^</em>]*'
```

but that does not work... thanks for your help!

Comment: `cat file.txt | grep ...` can be simplified to `grep ... file.txt`.

Comment: Do note that while what you want to do is possible (as demonstrated in answers below), [regex is generally not the right tool to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). For more robust solutions, use tools such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or a language that gives you access to a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correct regex would be `(?<=<em>).*?(?=</em>)`.

So, try:

```
grep -m 1 -oP '(?<=<em>).*?(?=</em>)' file.txt
```

Comment: That gives me this

Here is the text I want to parse out</em></td>
     <td class="ra">9.00</td>
     <td class="ra">297.00</td>
     <td class="ra">0.00</td>
     <td class="ra">0.00</td>
     <td class="ra">$0.00</td>
     <td class="ra">$0.50</td>
     <td class="ra"></td>
 </tr>

Comment: OK, so what it is doing is going to the last </em> which is in another text block below it... should have mentioned that, so I need the end to be the first occurrence of </em>... make sense?

Comment: @GregAlexander That could happen if the XML was all in one line, rather than nicely formatted as you show. Try to add a `?` after `*` as I did in the edit.